# Event logging - per Aggregate or one per Bounded Context?

Tags: domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

I'm working on an application (using Onion Architecture) and I want to have good log of entities' changes.

I'm struggling to find any good examples of what are the best practices - and I want to avoid bad architecture decisions at the beginning of my project.

Let's say I have few Entities (Aggregates in fact): `Customer`, `Product`, `Cart`. This entities are persisted in following tables: `Customers`, `Products` and `Carts`.

These entities produce such events: `CustomerCreated`, `CustomerDeleted`, `ProductCreated`, `ProductPriceChanged`, `CartCreated`, `CartProductAdded` etc.

**Question is:**

Should I have single table (single event log store) for all my entities, e.g. named `DomainEvents`?

Or is it better to have single table log per entity, e.g. `CustomersLog`, `CartsLog` and `ProductsLog`.

I'm personally in favor for the latter, because it is in accordance to SRP, and I believe will make log reading much faster (e.g. we can have INDEX on `Id` in `Logs` tables and we know that this `Id` represents given entity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a **domain event** may affect several aggregates, the event log shall be managed at the level of the domain. It's up to the event consumers to see how to change the states.

***Remark***: I have avoided to use "table",  because tables belong to the implementation and not the domain design: depending on your ORM,  events may stored in several tables if there are subtypes and single table inheritance cannot be used. What's important here is that it's at the level of the domain and not at the level of aggregates.

This is **fully in line with SRP**:  The domain event log shall log the events of the domain. And every entity shall process the events that are relevant to it. Event consumers are a kind of observers of the event log.   But domain events should in principle (at least, according to Evans) be managed separately from system events, because these are not relevant for the domain.

**Domain events are meant to be published** [for all those who need them](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/domain-event.html).  If you would decentralize your event log at the level of the aggregates,  you'd have a serious issue with separation of concerns:  every aggregate or  entity that causes events to be fired would have to know where to find the relevant event log.  And this kind of combinatorial explosion is exactly what event logs are meant to avoid.  Not even mentioning the dependency nightmare and the [principle of least knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: How about I want to audit the aggregate? Is the DomainEvents good source for that? Or rather separate tables, e.g. CustomersAuditLog would be better? Secound thought - yes, I know 'table' is implementation - however ultimately it has to be persisted; wouldn't such table be too heavy?

Comment: @MaciejPszczolinski DBMS are build to handle huge volumes.  So if you need to persist  the data it should not be an issue.  If it is, you have strategies to cope with it, deleting older events that are no longer needed (including for audit).

Comment: @MaciejPszczolinski Suppose I have an event `OrderedProductShipped`:  the same event would require an update of `Product` (inventory)  and an update of the `Order` (item status/parcel tracking).  But it's one and the same event. Now if you go for [event sourcing](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html), you'd still use an event store to persist the events.  This store should allow you to query by aggregate and entity. Of course, when processing the events in the first place, you may for performance reasons decide to duplicate some data or make some snapshots.

Comment: I don't want event sourcing (too complex for my needs). All I need is event log/audit. I want to know what is the history (mutations) that led to the current state of entities. The event `OrderedProductShipped` I would place in both `OrdersLog` and `ProductsLog` exactly because it is a mutation of both, that let to their current state. `OrderedProductShipped` can change `OrderId=111` and `ProductId=222`. Having single `DomainEvents` store, it would be hard to query "get me all events of OrderId 111". Wouldn't it?

Comment: @MaciejPszczolinski One reason more to to have one event log: for audit purpose, query it for the relevant objects; you then have a single source of the truth. I mean answering questions such as “give me all events for order 111” is a basic functionality of an event store. You just need an object type and an object identifier.  If the leading ERP manages huge volumes of change events this way, why wouldn’t it work for you?

Comment: In case of single event log, and having `OrderedProductShipped` example (it impacted 2 entities) we had to persist this events 2 times in event log. One will be `ObjectType:Order, ObjectId:111`, and second will be `ObjectType:Product, ObjectId:222`. Right?

Comment: @MaciejPszczolinski Not necessarily,  "OrderedProductShipped" is one event. The event would of course say what item (entity) of the order (aggregate was shipped).  Or more probably will it refer to a a shipping id which says that. What about this single event would be processed 2 times: once by an order handler which would raise in the end an OrderStatusUpdate event,  and the product handler which would raise in the end an InventoryUpdated event?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109310/discussion-between-maciej-pszczolinski-and-christophe).

Comment: I just read that DomainEvents are produced by Aggregates. Thus, each domain event can be associated with exact aggregate, thus I believe we can have DomainEventLog per Aggregate. Later of couse, this event can be dispatched and trigger changes in other Aggregates, but it will be stored only one place - an DomainEventLogPerAggregate.